# Spark map with many String concatenation

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, optimization

I am looking for a way to optimize a code like this one:

```
// for each line do many string concatenations
myRdd.map{x => "some_text" + x._1 + "some_other_text" + x._4 + ...}
```

I just read that use a

```
s"some_text${x._1}..."
```

will be replaced by a basic string concatenation like in my map.

So my first thought was to use a StringBuilder like

```
   myRdd.map{x => 
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    sb.append("some_text")
    sb.append(x._1)
    ...
    sb
```

But the StringBuilder ojbect will be created for each line. **Is there a best practice for this kind of optimization** like declaring the StringBuilder somewhere else (an object or a class attribut) and use always the same instance in my map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disassemble your code `myRdd.map{x => "some_text" + x._1 + "some_other_text" + x._4 + ...}`, it would show something like this:

```
NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
DUP
LDC 24
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> (I)V
LDC "some_text"
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ALOAD 0
INVOKEVIRTUAL scala/Tuple2._1 ()Ljava/lang/Object;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
LDC "some_other_text"
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ALOAD 0
INVOKEVIRTUAL scala/Tuple2._2 ()Ljava/lang/Object;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
```

So as you can see, scala compiler optimizes string concatenations to use StringBuilder and there is not really a difference between your first code snippet and second (Javac also does that). The first solution is preferable (especially version with string interpolation) because it's more readable.

You could reuse your string builder by resetting it using `setLength` method.

```
val sb = new StringBuilder()

myRdd.map{x =>
  sb.setLength(0)
  sb.append("some_text" + x._1 + "some_other_text" + x._2)
  sb.toString
}
```

But I don't know if it's worth it. String builders created in this loop won't leave [`eden` memory](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-the-java-memory-model-and-the-garbag) region and will be immediately cleaned out by GC.

The downside of using an approach with `StringBuilder` is, it is a lot less readable, not functional and ugly. If you don't have serious problems with performance caused by this fragment I would stay with string interpolation. Remember [Premature optimization is a root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a global `StringBuilder` which is mutable, consider using a `List` to store the text by index and `foldLeft` to concatenate the text, as shown below:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  ("f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
))

val textList = List((1, "x1"), (3, "x3"), (4, "x4"))

rdd.map( r => textList.foldLeft("")( (acc, kv) =>
  acc + kv._2 + r.productElement(kv._1 - 1)
) ).
collect
// res1: Array[String] = Array(x1ax3cx4d, x1fx3hx4i)
```